# How to create a function that accepts N number of elements in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to create a new function for this set of codes I have done. So that I may call the function for any number of elements for my selenium testing.

[image: current-code]

Should I be using List or something could be more readable?

Comment: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question. Please provide the text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java [variable arguments/varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). It allows you to pass a number of objects as input parameter and you can access it internally as an array of objects. So your function definition would be like:

```
public bool visibilityOfAllElelemnts(WebElement ...elements) {
   for (WebElement element: elements) {
     // do something here
   }
}
```

And you can call it the same way you are doing it right now:

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(currentUniformBuilder, rosterTab, currentBuilderSelected, viewTogether, thumbnailViews));
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending this. Used the idea to create function `public static void waitForElements(WebDriver driver, WebElement ...elements)`